# ssh server close connection after password attempt

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, putty, sshd

I am trying to access to remote server via ssh. I couldn't do it via ssh command in CLI, but with same credentials I can access via putty ssh.

I am using ubuntu 12.04.
I don't have access to ssh server, so I can't change sshd config file.

Access to ssh server is possible form other machines via ssh CLI command, but from my mashine this is not working. Credentials are proper because I can connect via putty, and I don't get any message from server when I enter password. It just close connection.

command i use to connect via ssh in CLI is:

```
ssh -vv someuser@somehost.com
```

This is output:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to somehost.com [53.52.81.241] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/djuki/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/djuki/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/djuki/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/djuki/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/djuki/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/djuki/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-                  nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-    hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-     v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-    sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 125/256
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA e5:55:0d:1a:0e:2e:c5:03:db:05:c3:85:af:cf:bd:cd
debug1: Host 'somehost.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/djuki/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 499/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/djuki/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/djuki/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/djuki/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/djuki/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/djuki/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/djuki/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
someuser@somehost.com's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 30.52.83.243
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can try with `ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no someuser@somehost.com` ; it should make the `Unspecified GSS failure` messages disappear.

Then, if you are able to connect with putty, you can connect and then run `sshd` in debug mode on a higher port (you do not need to be root to do that, but you need no firewall blocking all the ports) :

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d -e -p1234
```

and then you can try to connect in CLI with

```
ssh -p 1234 someuser@somehost.com
```

and you will see, in your putty session, the reason why the server closes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for one of the following,

1. LoginGraceTime and make sure that is set to a time limit that you can enter your password. Otherwise it will close the connection if your request doesn't get authenticated within the timeframe. (example: this will give you a 1min window, LoginGraceTime 60)
2. "UseDNS no" will make sure sshd would not try to resolve the hostname. If the ssh client computer and the server are using two different nameservers and they point to different IPs for the same hostname might end up locking you out. So "UseDNS no" would resolve such problems.
3. "PasswordAuthentication yes" will make sure the SSHd accepts user entered passwords.

That's all I have come across for this issue.